# Is it possible to get locals() and globals() from an upper stack frame?

Tags: python

If I eval something in Python:

```
eval("a + b")
```

This will evaluate the expression using the current scope (both locals and globals).

What I am developing requires that an expression be evaluated "later". Such word implies that I want to keep the current scope (i.e. `locals()` and `globals()`). But I want to pass such values... transparently, or fetch them from an upper stack frame. Consider this implementation (actually, this one exists):

```
def __eval(self, expr):
    if isinstance(expr, (list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, Expression)):
        return Expression.eval(expr, self)
    elif callable(expr):
        try:
            return expr(self)
        except (AttributeError, IndexError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return UNDEFINED
    else:
        try:
            return eval(expr, {}, {'self': self})
        except (AttributeError, IndexError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return UNDEFINED
```

This implementation is explained as follows:

- If I use an expression object (I actually developed such object), then I evaluate such expression using the current object (after all, this function is a method). This part needs not help, it is fully developed.
- If I use a callable, I execute the callable (e.g. a lambda expression).
- If I use a string, that will be a python expression, and I want such evaluation be performed using the call-time `locals()` and `globals()`.

I know I could explicitly call:

```
o._O__eval("self.a + self.b", globals(), locals())
#THIS WOULD REQUIRE to alter the method to allow two additional dict parameters
#NO, I will not call this function directly, but lets follow the example
```

But I'd like to get such `globals()` and `locals` without the user passing it explicitly and make use of such values in the `eval`.

**Question**: Is it possible to get the `locals()` and `globals()` from an upper stack frame?

Comment: In this design, do consider the "what if everyone wanted to do the same thing you are?" problem. That is to say, suppose you get what you want and then I want to write another convenience function that calls your `__eval`. How am I supposed to tell it, "no, not *this* stack frame, keep going up another level"?

Comment: if you dare to call `scope['$eval']("a + b")` which -for reasons I will not explain here- is the actual way to call the __eval (yes, it's sort of an AngularJS port to Python, but partially) then you would be using the lexical scope of the call-time (such lexical scope has an extra processing to have 'self' pointing to the current $scope object). It works now :).

Comment: However, althought I asked for this strange use case, it's not the mostly-needed use case. $eval would always be called inside a $watch call (after all, it is -partially- an AngularJS $rootScope port).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really consider just *passing in* `globals()` and `locals()`:

```
def __eval(self, expr, eval_globals=None, eval_locals=None):
    if eval_globals is None:
        eval_globals = globals()
    if eval_locals is None:
        eval_locals = eval_globals()
```

If that is not an option for you, you *can* access the parent frame with the [`sys._getframe()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), and the locals and globals are attributes on that frame:

```
def __eval(self, expr, eval_globals=None, eval_locals=None):
    call_frame = sys._getframe(1)
    eval_globals, eval_locals = call_frame.f_globals, call_frame.f_locals
```